# Why JSTL works when URI defined as /jstl/core_rt but not /jsp/jstl/core in embedded jetty?

Tags: jetty, jstl, embedded-jetty

I can't seem to get my JSTL library working in my embedded jetty project working.

My taglib line seems to be giving me grief, and it all changes when I use different URIs. Here is the line I would want to use:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

I first tried using the normal URI http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core but that throws the error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /bad.jsp(1,61) PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

However when I change the URI to http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt. It works!

Another thing I noticed, if I have the old JSTL 1.0 url (http://java.sun.com/jstl/core) I get the following error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /bad-el.jsp(4,0) PWC6236: According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions

Now another preplexing thing I have noticed, this all works in IntelliJ! Which leads me to believe that there is a classpath problem, but the libraries should be all the same when I embed them inside the war. I think I am missing something.

So, what my question boils down to, what library do I need, or what configuration do I need to have to make this work properly?

Here are the current questions I have tried to follow but did not resolve my issues:

- [cannot load JSTL taglib within embedded Jetty server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151075/cannot-load-jstl-taglib-within-embedded-jetty-server)
- [Embedded Jetty fails to load JSP taglibs when classpath specified in jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020495/embedded-jetty-fails-to-load-jsp-taglibs-when-classpath-specified-in-jar)
- [Jetty 8 standalone doesn't detect jstl taglib jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379160/jetty-8-standalone-doesnt-detect-jstl-taglib-jar)
- [JSTL not parsed in a JSP page running on an embedded Jetty instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519161/jstl-not-parsed-in-a-jsp-page-running-on-an-embedded-jetty-instance)
- and [many others](https://www.google.com/search?q=embedded+jetty+jstl&oq=embedded+jetty+jstl)

I have a [sample project](https://github.com/baens/simple-java-web-platform) that one could checkout and try out.

Comment: Did you check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944163/difference-between-core-and-core-rt-jstl-tag ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want the JSTL uri to work, you should know that jstl is two files.

1. jstl-1.2.jar
2. jstl-api-1.2.jar

so look for them in the internet or go to the maven repo and download the jars