# JSTL fmt not working

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl, struts1

Below is my codes, everything works fine but the fmt not.

**web.xml**

```
 <jsp-config>       
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/tags/jstl-fmt.tld</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tags/fmt.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/tags/jstl-fmt-1_0.tld</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tags/fmt-1_0.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
         <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/tags/jstl-fmt-1_0-rt.tld</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tags/fmt-1_0-rt.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
         <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/tags/jstl-c.tld</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tags/c.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/tags/jstl-c-1_0.tld</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tags/c-1_0.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
         <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/tags/jstl-c-1_0-rt.tld</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tags/c-1_0-rt.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
   </jsp-config>
```

**Sample.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tags/jstl-fmt.tld" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tags/jstl-c.tld" prefix="c" %>

  <html:form action="/UserAction.do">
    <fmt:message key="message.username"/>
    <c:out value="Hello" />
 </html:form>
```

**ApplicationResource.properties**

```
message.username=Username
```

**tags directory**

```
\projectName\web\WEB-INF\tags
```

[image: Tags]
**Result**

```
 Hello // from core
    ???message.username??? //the fmt:message.username not working
```

Could anyone help me out, why fmt didn't works ? I have tried creating 3 or more projects with using jstl. All the jstl is working but only the fmt not.

Comment: try `<c:out value="${applicationScope.message.username}" />` instead

Comment: or try `<c:out value"${initParam:message.username}"/>`

Comment: @user2511414, thanks for your reply but I want to use fmt tag

Comment: What server are you using where you still need to declare taglibs in your web.xml?!

Comment: @DaveNewton,Apache tomcat. Thanks for your reply I have found out the solution by just now

Comment: What *version* of Tomcat? The need to declare taglibs went away years ago.

Comment: @DaveNewton Version 7.0.27.0

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have try another way but not working http://stackoverflow.com/q/18944163/2291134. This is the question that I have asked but no reply. Then I tried out this way, it works.

Comment: I don't really see how any of this is related to what I'm telling you, namely, that having to manually declare taglibs in your web.xml hasn't been necessary for years. It also doesn't explain the ancient versions of the taglibs, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: Why down vote the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I solved it.
Following codes have to be inserted in **web.xml**

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>com.projectName.resources.ApplicationResource</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: I am trying to use your solution. I have the same problem. Is the com.projectName supposed to read exactly like that or is it supposed to be the name of my project? If my project, where can it be found?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what is the path of your ApplicationResources file within your project? Also where do you find the project name?

Comment: As you can see the answer above, the path is com.projectName.resources and the projectName may not be your exactly your project name. It can be any name eg: com.home.town.resources.  It just a path name. In my case, i used my project name to create the resources path.

Comment: When this finally worked for you, what was the location of your ApplicationResources file? Was it located in a subpath of /WEB-INF/classes?

Comment: No, it was located at src/java/com/projectName/resources