# Include specific JAR files in skinny WARs with Maven

Tags: maven, jar, war, ear

I've been having some problems with a WAR module and its difficulty in loading a taglib. I kept getting this exception:

```
JSPG0047E: Unable to locate tag library for uri http://www.springframework.org/tags/form 
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.tagfiledep.TagFileDependencyVisitor.visitCustomTagStart(TagFileDependencyVisitor.java:76)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.JspVisitor.processJspElement(JspVisitor.java:366)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.JspVisitor.processChildren(JspVisitor.java:419)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.JspVisitor.processJspElement(JspVisitor.java:369)
...
```

After a bit of searching, I found a lot of suggestions that the spring jars need to be on the application's classpath. I checked in my EAR's lib folder and sure enough, spring-web and spring-webmvc were there.

It should be noted that the EAR is built with skinny WARs - since they use most of the same libraries, all library files are in `MyAppEAR/lib` instead of `MyAppEAR/MyWAR1/WEB-INF/lib`, `MyAppEAR/MyWAR2/WEB-INF/lib`, `MyAppEAR/MyWAR3/WEB-INF/lib`, etc...

I did finally manage to resolve this missing taglib error, but I had to move spring-web and spring-webmvc to `MyAppEAR/MyWAR1/WEB-INF/lib`.

So I have a couple of questions:

1. Is this the *only* way to fix this problem?
2. If so, how can I build a sort-of skinny WAR using maven? Currently, the EAR part of the POM looks like this:

   ```
   <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.8</version>
     <configuration>
       <applicationName>MyAppEAR</applicationName>
       <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
       <skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars>
   ```

I guess I could turn off skinny WARs and then have some other step remove all libraries from the WAR files and copy them to MyAppEAR/lib *except* for the spring web jars, but I am hoping there's a better solution.

Comment: Great question. I have the same problem when running a Selenium test against Jetty (instantiated programmatically) from within JUnit. I feed Jetty 'src/main/webapp', where it expects to find these libraries. Just being on the classpath (these libraries are put on the classpath by Maven) seems not enough.

Comment: @SanderVerhagen: Maybe this relates to your problem with Jetty: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020495/embedded-jetty-fails-to-load-jsp-taglibs-when-classpath-specified-in-jar

Comment: This is a very good question. I'm asking myself if skinny WARs are still a good solution as they tend to make problems. See [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987266/why-doesnt-jsf-2-0-ri-mojarra-scan-my-class-annotations) for the reason why some JARs have to live in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it working.

In the WAR's POM file:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
      <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar,WEB-INF/*.xmi</packagingExcludes>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
             <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
             <classpathPrefix>../../WEB-INF/lib/</classpathPrefix>
       </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This causes the generated WAR file to have a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file with classpath entries that look like `../WEB-INF/lib/$someJarFile` - that is the relative path from the WAR to the EAR's library folder. I guess the WAR *needs* to have the classpath specified, having the libraries in the EAR just isn't enough.

Comment: While your suggestion migth work, I would consider it a hack. The war won't deploy anymore if it is outside the EAR. That's why [the maven wiki](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Solving+the+Skinny+Wars+problem) suggests fixing this in the EAR plugin and that's why the EAR plugin got the [`skinnyWars` parameter](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html#skinnyWars). So IMHO the problem should be fixed on the EAR side rather than on the WAR side. Unfortunately I can't provide a better solution for now :(

Comment: @MartinHöller: I agree, I don't really like it much. We've had better luck with new EAR projects on newer versions of WebSphere. It was mostly just this one legacy project which has been giving problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues myself - I just couldn't access Spring or Sitemesh's TLDs when my spring JAR files were in my `ear/lib` folder!

Including the classpath in the MANIFEST was causing my app server go haywire (since all dependencies were being loaded twice).

(Yes, I also have `skinnyWars` set to true in my `maven-ear-plugin`).

The only way I could have gone round the issue was by including `Spring` and `sitemesh` by including them in `maven-war-plugin`'s configuration:

```
<packagingExcludes>%regex[WEB-INF/lib/(?!spring|sitemesh).*.jar]</packagingExcludes>
```

Not the most elegant solution, but the least damaging I could find.

This is my full configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>

                <!--
                Q. Why is this set?
                A. maven-ear-plugin in our EAR modules have `skinnyWars` enabled to that WAR files 
                   would not include any third-party libraries in the WAR's WEB-INF/lib folder, however 
                   this does not work for ejbs (like our own EJB modules).

                   We'll need to exclude them from here anyway (except for a few select JARS)...
                -->                 
                <packagingExcludes>%regex[WEB-INF/lib/(?!spring|sitemesh).*.jar]</packagingExcludes>

                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>false</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

---

PS. My setup is JBoss EAP 6.x and an ear file with several EJBs, WARs and third-party JARs.